# Alternative proof request that $Aut(\mathbb{Q}_p)=\{Id\}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, alternative-proof, p-adic-number-theory

I am working through Neukrich's Algebraic number theory book, and just read the chapter introducing the p-adics. At this stage we know the definition of the p-adics as the fraction field of the projective limit of $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$, a couple consequences of this defnition, and importantly nothing about the p-adic absolute value.

Yet exercise 2.1.5 of the book requires us to show $Aut(\mathbb{Q}_p)=\{Id\}$. I failed and so tried to search online for a solution, but they all use the p-adic absolute value, the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ and showing continuity of automorphisms. However given the place of this exercise, I am wondering whether anybody knows of any proof which doesn't require these techniques.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any way other than either proving $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is fixed, or that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: As @user10354138 says, there are some passages that any route to this objective must pass through. Think of what you need to do to prove the analogous result for the reals, $\Bbb R$. You need to observe that the topology (via inequalities ($\le$) ) has a purely algebraic definition (something is nonnegative iff it’s a square); that an automorphism of $\Bbb R$ will automatically be continuous; and that the rationals are dense in the reals. It’s the same for $\Bbb Q_p$.